# Force between loops

Tags: mathematical-physics

[image]

It is physics (force between loops) but the highlighted term is equal to zero and I don't understand it. It is from Stokes' theorem but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int \vec{dl}.\nabla f = \int\int curl(\nabla f)da =0 $ since the curl of a gradient is always $0$. Here I used $f$ for $\dfrac{1}{r_{12}}$

Comment: if i understand, F=r (vector)/r^3,   F=∇f, where f=1/r, F is conservative, so ∇xF=0, so the ∇(∇f)=0

Comment: Yes indeed. Though in your last equation it should be the curl of gradient of $f$ is zero; your equation makes it seem like you are taking the gradient of the gradient of f.

Comment: yes, do you think that ∇2(there is in the picture) is equal to ∇X(∇f)?? Thank you a lot!

Comment: No that's something different. Notice that you have two sets of variables here $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$. The notation $r_{12}$ means $r_{12}=|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|$, hence the notation $\nabla_{2}$ means you take the gradient with respect to $\vec{r_2}$.

Comment: so a good explanation is that exist f that is F=∇f, so F is  conservative, so ∇X(∇f)=0, so the integral (highlighted term) is equal to zero ??

Comment: yes that is correct.